# VMWare Player freezes when computer wakes from sleep

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware-player

VMWare Player runs Ubuntu 13.04 perfectly, as long as my computer doesn't go to sleep. As soon as the computer's woken from sleep, I am greeted with a frozen screen of my VM, and my HD light shines solidly and I cannot click anything.

This is only started happening after I bumped up the VM's RAM, but taking it back down again does not fix this error. VMWare Player is running in Windows 7.

Any ideas or alternate products?

Comment: What do the VMware logs tell?

Comment: Where can I find these?

Comment: Normally there are log files in the directory of the virtual machine.